# What's meant by "identity-based Map" and "topology-preserving object graph transformations"?

Tags: java

The [JavaTutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html) have this to say on `IdentityHashMap`:

> `IdentityHashMap` is an **identity-based `Map`** implementation based on a
>   hash table. This class is useful for **topology-preserving object graph
>   transformations,** such as serialization or deep-copying. To perform
>   such transformations, you need to maintain an identity-based "node
>   table" that keeps track of which objects have already been seen.
>   Identity-based maps are also used to maintain
>   object-to-meta-information mappings in dynamic debuggers and similar
>   systems. Finally, identity-based maps are useful in thwarting "spoof
>   attacks" that are a result of intentionally perverse equals methods
>   because `IdentityHashMap` never invokes the `equals` method on its keys.
>   An added benefit of this implementation is that it is fast.

Could someone please explain in Simple English what is meant by both

- "identity-based Map" and
- "topology-preserving object graph transformations"?

Comment: Did you read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html)?

Comment: No, because I assumed a beginner's tutorial would have to be easier than a piece of technical documentation. Probably should have, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) - as you always should if you need to understand a class.

> This class implements the Map interface with a hash table, using reference-equality in place of object-equality when comparing keys (and values). In other words, in an `IdentityHashMap`, two keys `k1` and `k2` are considered equal if and only if `(k1==k2)`. (In normal Map implementations (like `HashMa`p) two keys `k1` and `k2` are considered equal if and only if `(k1==null ? k2==null : k1.equals(k2))`.)

and

> A typical use of this class is topology-preserving object graph transformations, such as serialization or deep-copying. To perform such a transformation, a program must maintain a "node table" that keeps track of all the object references that have already been processed. The node table must not equate distinct objects even if they happen to be equal.

Answer (score 4):

"Identity-based `Map`" means that keys are compared via `==` for identity, not with `equals` for equality.

"Topology-preserving object graph transformations" means that when you have some object structure and transform it to another object structure, you want to preserve topology i.e. relation between nodes in the original and the target graph. For this you need to map nodes via identity, not equality.

Consider the following example. You have tree of `Foo` classes (tree defined via `Foo parent` field) which you want to transform into a tree `Bar` classes (again `Bar` has `Bar parent`) field. For each `Foo` you'll need to create a new `Bar` but just once. To keep track of that mapping you'll create a `Map<Foo, Bar>`. You'll also use this map to find parent `Bar`s.

The problem is, however that if two `Foo`s are `equals` you may get the wrong parent `Bar` when getting it from the tracking map. This will break the topology in the tree of `Bar`s, you'll just hang the node to the wrong parent.

To avoid this you need identity comparison, not equality. This is what `IdentitiyHashMap` does.

Answer (score 2):

A simple code is better than thousand words, see below:-

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        //Two Keys
        Integer key1=new Integer("1");
        Integer key2=new Integer("1");

        //A normal map
        Map<Integer, String> map=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        map.put(key1, "Hello");
        map.put(key2, "World");
        System.out.println(map); //Output:- {1=World}

        //An identity HashMap
        Map<Integer, String> identityMap=new IdentityHashMap<Integer, String>();
        identityMap.put(key1, "Hello");
        identityMap.put(key2, "World");
        System.out.println(identityMap); //Output:- {1=Hello, 1=World}
    }
```

What you observed above:-

- In first case, key1 is compared to key2 by equals method.
- In second case, key1 is compared to key2 by == method.

> So, in case of IdentityHashMap, two keys will be equal if and only if
>   they refer to the same location in memory which is an Identity
>   Equality, hence this map is a special implementation that only
>   supports Identity based Equality.

*Objects have references to other objects which may in turn have references to more objects, this will result in object graph.*
If you want to transform the object graph and maintain the object relationships, you will be doing it on Type i.e. Reference and not on actual values of Objects. If you use IdentityHashMap, it will preserve the original topology of object references as it doesn't rely on hashCode(..) and equals(..) method of objects.